# Google Chrome extension content_script sendResponse does not work

Tags: google-chrome-extension

First I made a query from popup

```js
requestForCodeMirrorElement(){ 
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {name: "GetChosenCodeMirrorText"}, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
  }
```

Then I add this in my content_script

```html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.name == "GetChosenCodeMirrorText"){
        var codeMirrorContent='empty';

        document.addEventListener('GetContent', function (e){
            codeMirrorContent =e.detail.content;
            console.log(codeMirrorContent);
            sendResponse({chosenCodeMirrorText: codeMirrorContent});
        });


        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('get_codemirror_script.js');
        (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
        s.onload = function() {
            s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
        };
    }
    return true;
});
```

I wrote this file called get_codemirror_script.js and it has been added to manifest.json.

When I test the code in Chrome, I get codeMirrorContent in console so I think get_codemirror_script.js does not have any problem.

When I change my content_script to this:

```html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.name == "GetChosenCodeMirrorText"){
        var codeMirrorContent='empty';
        
        sendResponse({chosenCodeMirrorText: "forTest"});
        
        document.addEventListener('GetContent', function (e){
            codeMirrorContent =e.detail.content;
            console.log(codeMirrorContent);
        });


        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('get_codemirror_script.js');
        (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
        s.onload = function() {
            s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
        };
    }
});
```

I get "forTest" in popup console. So I guess there should be some problem with sendRequest. How can I fix it?

---

UPDATE:
Just for reference, I used to inject embedded code (see [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)) instead of injecting file like what I described above. And that time it works fine.

Comment: Do you have an example of where I should put "return true"?

Comment: Before you exit. So: between your last two lines: `} return true;});`

Comment: I just edited my code. But seems I still don't get anything in my popup

Comment: I restarted Chrome and it worked. Thanks!.